# Button instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

i want to make app in python so i have just started, i want to click button and graph should be displayed !!!

But its not allowing me to do so.

**code snippet:**

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def schart2(stock_sym): 
    df
    df.astype(float)
    labels =      ['day0','day1','day2','day3','day4','day5','day6','day7','day8','day9','day10','day11','day12','day13','day14','day15','day16','day17','day18','day19','day20','day21','day22','day23','day24','day25','day26','day27','day28','day29','day30']

    df.columns=labels
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.15, right=0.99, top=0.95)
    ax=plt.imshow(df, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("RdPu"), interpolation="nearest",aspect="auto")
    plt.xticks(range(len(labels)), labels, rotation=90, va="top", ha="center")

    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title("Return rate Retention")
    plt.xlabel("Retention Days")
    plt.ylabel("Total Days")
    fig=ax.get_figure()
    plt.show()

class StockChart(Frame):
    def __init__(self, stock_sym=''):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.create_widgets(stock_sym)
        self.makeWidgets(stock_sym)

    def create_widgets(self, stock_sym):
        self.makeWidgets = tk.Button(self)
        self.makeWidgets["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.makeWidgets["command"] = self.makeWidgets
        self.makeWidgets.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def makeWidgets(self, stock_sym):
        #self.f = graphData(stock_sym,12,26)
        self.f = schart2(stock_sym)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    StockChart('ACAD').mainloop()
```

And the **ERROR** is:

```
    self.makeWidgets(stock_sym)
AttributeError: Button instance has no __call__ method
```

Am I doing this completely wrong or is there an easy way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be like 15 or 20 bugs & errors in the code you posted... Did you write this or is it a composite of cuts and pastes from various sources? Did it ever run, at an earlier stage?
Can you post something simpler, that produced one error after you changed something on a working piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable

```
self.makeWidgets = tk.Button(self)
```

Has the same name as your class method

```
def makeWidgets(self, stock_sym):
```

Try first to change this